# Dúvida sobre o Messagebox

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma dúvida sobre o nosso famoso `MessageBox.Show();`, esse comando trata-se de um evento, método o que seria??

Outra dúvida é sobre instanciar objeto, no exemplo abaixo estamos pegando nosso formulário login e criando uma variável que será a nossa referencia do objeto =  recebe objeto `frmLogin`.

Minha dúvida é, posso dizer que o meu objeto seria `frmLogin` ou `entra`

```
frmLogin entra = new frmLogin()

entra.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

> - O `MessageBox`é uma classe pública da `namespace System.Windows.Forms{}`;
> - O `.Show()` é um método estático da classe ´MessageBox´ que tem como o tipo de retorno um ´DialogResult´;

É possível visualizar essa informações no Metadados na IDE Visual Studio, selecionando o nome do método ou classe e apertando a tecla `F12 (Ir para definições)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais Sobre `MessageBox`: [Documentação da Classe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

> No caso:
>
> ```
> frmLogin entra = new frmLogin()
> entra.Show();
> ```
>
> `entra` é um objeto que faz referência a `classe parcial frmLogin` que
>   tem como `base a classe pública Form`. Nesta situação o objeto será
>   instanciado e logo em seguida é invocado o Método `.Show()` que tem
>   como função exibir o controle(`Form`).